# Magnetic field between 4 wires with the same current

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

if I have 4 long wires with a current I and all of them have the same distance from each other (looked at from the front you'd have a square) shouldn't the magnetic field vanish in the middle of all 4 wires? Of course, only if 2 of the wires had a different current direction as the others.

I'm not sure about this as I don't thoroughly understand superposition of magnetic fields. (I know that you can add the vectors together but I can't really imagine how to think of it geometrically, kind of).

Comment: Hint: draw the field lines (with direction) for a single wire; then for each of the four wires. Add the field vectors in the center. In case of two wires with opposite current: there are two ways to arrange them; consider each of them.

Comment: You don't need to do any calculations, consider the symmetry of the system. Of course the force would have to be zero in the centre, otherwise which direction would it point?